# How to apply a function to a column in DF

Tags: r, function, tapply

I understand my problem but didn't find a solution. 
I want to apply a user define function to some columns. 
but I seem to equal String to a Vector.

my func:

```
shape_side<-function(shapeN,area)# calc the side or radius upon a given area {

      ifelse(shapeN == "square",return(sqrt(area)),

      ifelse(shapeN == "circle",return(sqrt(area/3.14)),
      ifelse(shapeN =="triangle", return(sqrt(area/(sqrt(3)/4))),)))
     }
```

tapply(shapesDF$area,shapesDF$shape,shape_side)

So I want to calc the side of every shape upon its area (shape and area are columns)

Comment: You don't need `return` wihtin the `ifelse`.  Change it to `ifelse(shapeN == "square", sqrt(area), ifelse(shapeN == "circle", sqrt(area/3.14), sqrt(area/(sqrt(3)/4))), NA))`

Comment: Can you also post a small reproducible example and expected output